# Add even elements in Prolog- Problem with 'amt' variable

Tags: prolog, addition

I'm trying to figure out how to add even elements in a list (i've studied examples but cant do it on my own yet, need your help in pinning down my lack of understanding to a specific area).

The input I used is start([1,2,3,4,5]). There is no compilation error, but I dont get any output. I'm not sure what the logical error is..could you please advise?

**(please see below for the latest update, after revising my code, now it works, and the problem lies in the way I use 'amt', but I dont know why!)**

*Original code that didnt work:*

```
start(X):- add(X,1,amt), write(amt).

add([],_,0).  
add([H|Tail],Cnt,amt):-
  T is (Cnt mod 2), T == 0, Cnt1 is Cnt + 1, add(Tail,Cnt1,Y), amt is H+Y; 

  T is (Cnt mod 2), T =\=0, Cnt1 is Cnt + 1, add(Tail, Cnt1, amt).
```

**Latest Update:**

I replaced 'amt' with a 'S', and it works! But why wldnt it work with 'amt'?

*here's the revised code that works:*

```
start(X):- add(X,1,S), write(S).

add([],_,0).  
add([H|Tail],Cnt,S):-
  T is (Cnt mod 2), T == 0, Cnt1 is Cnt + 1, add(Tail,Cnt1,Y), S is H+Y; 

  T is (Cnt mod 2), T =\=0, Cnt1 is Cnt + 1, add(Tail, Cnt1, S).
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you intending to display amt1?

Comment: yes, amt1 is supposed to add the even elements and be displayed.

Comment: i've  revised the code, tried to work on the recursive portion and fixed the 'amt1' variable which wasnt matching earlier, still not giving output.

Comment: okay, so i've pinpointed the problem to the 'amt' variable...do you know why i cant use 'amt' and have to use a single letter variable instd?

Comment: 'amt' is an atom; variables must start with an uppercase letter or '_'.